# Why am I getting restart prompts after installing an update with /quiet /norestart on Windows?

Tags: windows, windows-7, updates

I'm installing updates for Windows 7 using the following syntax from a batch file:

`wusa.exe <...>.msu /quiet /norestart`

The update is installed quietly but I still get a dialog prompting me to restart.

Does `/norestart` not suppress this? I don't want my computer to restart while there are still updates to be installed by the batch file.

[image]

Comment: No; You still have to restart to finish the install of the update.  /norestart only prevents the necessary restart

Comment: If I have a batch file that is installing updates while unattended, will the system restart on its own after 10 minutes due to this dialog and interrupt the script?

Comment: If you want the system to automatically restart you should avoid /norestart

Comment: You misunderstand. I want to avoid having the system restart prematurely before the batch file has completed.